# RunDLL ~$WT.FAT error when accessing HDD

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8, backup, external-hard-drive

I can't access my hard drive. When I try to do it, I get the following error:

> RUnDLL, there was a problem starting ~$WT.FAT The specified module could not be found.

My computer was infected with a virus. My hard disk contains a shortcut and the shortcut contains all files. I don't want to format it. I tried troubleshooting it but none of the solutions I found on the internet helped.

What could be the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: What do you mean by "the shortcut contains all files"? Does that mean all the files are accessible if you follow the shortcut?

Comment: yes , I can access my files only if I can open the shortcut .

Comment: Then I advise you to copy all your files off the drive (ensure they're all clean), then reformat it and copy your data back.

Comment: This is the Problem my friend I cannot open it so I can't copy any file, When I try to open my external hard drive on my friends computer it shows the same problem over there also .

Comment: Ah, so you actually *can't* open the shortcut, and what you really meant was that if only you could do so, you'd be able to access your files. In that case search the net for data recovery software and try a few to see what works best to retrieve your files.